# How do I stop a button event from posting in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a standard view and some standard `input` tags without `runat=server`:

```
<button id="submit">submit</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

Pressing either causes the page to submit. Instead, I want them to do nothing since I'm handling the `click` event with JQuery. How do I do this?

**EDIT**

Here is my jquery code

```
$('#submit').bind('click', submit_click);

function submit_click() {
    alert('clicked submit');
}
```

Comment: Postback?  runat server?  Are you sure this is MVC?

Comment: Yes - 100%, i enter a controller, i render my view etc. It is mvc 100%

Comment: If you don't want a submit button. Why you don't replace them with a simple input button `<input type="button" />`.

Comment: @Mehdi: You should post this as an answer :) Solved my issue

Comment: @keith, thanks. But I thought there was something that I didn't realize. ;)

Answer (score 15):

### Set the `type` to `button`:

This will prevent the Form from Submitting.
No additional javascript functions necessary.
Note: When this property is *not* set, it *will* default to `submit`.

I assume your `button` Controls are inside a `form` tag or `Html.BeginForm()` code block.
Below are some Examples:

```
<button onclick="alert('You Clicked Implicit Submit.')">Implicit Submit</button>//Post Back Form.
<button onclick="alert('You Clicked Submit.')" type="submit">Submit</button>//Post Back Form.
<button onclick="alert('You Clicked Button.')" type="button">Button</button>//Stay on Client Page.
```

For a simple redirect (without Posting the Form back to its Default Action) you could also do this:

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'" type="button">Redirect</button>
```

Special thanks to the Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17452739/555798

Comment: Changing the type to "button" works only if someone does not change the type back to "submit" via developers tools in any browser.

Comment: @mchar With browser dev tools you may also edit the HTML to add new Buttons that Submit, as well as edit/add Javascript on the page and a bunch of other stuff that is out of scope for this Question, so I don't understand your point.  Does the Answer above not sufficiently answer the Question?  If there is a security concern, then consider researching how to protect your site better (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903828/555798) or posting a new Question about it.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend your answer, and true, it covers the the question posted, however my point is still valid plus all the rest you mentioned in your comment. Someone might don't know about it and thinks that the form will not be submitted whatsoever, like I did, but in reality, it will.

Comment: @mchar It's not a valid point. You're basically just saying "I can change HTML and JS in such a way as to call public endpoints and that's a problem.", but that's not a problem or point of consideration, really.

Answer (score 8):

In your event handler you need to do:

```
$("button").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // do something
});
```

taken from: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29

**update**
This should work in your code:

```
$('#submit').bind('click', submit_click);

function submit_click(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked submit');
}
```

Comment: I live this! -- but how do i apply it to my code? I will update my jquery code on my question

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your click event bindings:

```
$('#submit').bind('click', submit_click);

function submit_click() {
    alert('clicked submit');
    return false;
}
```

Returning false stops the regular behaviour of the button happening, instead only performing your code.