# button with no postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Well i have a asp.net page where i have a button that im using to execute a JavaScript... but after the JavaScript has run the page reloads(postback) how can i avoid that?

```
<button onclick="printElement('content');">Print</button>
```

Comment: i tried to return false from the printElement function and that had no effect..

Comment: did you add a return in front of the call to printElement?

Comment: well placing the return false in the printElement function did not seem to change any thing but placing it like you 2 posted seemed to work thanks alot!

Comment: If the form should be submitted if printElement returns true than simply `return printElement('content');`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

you need to use `return false`

```
<button onclick="printElement('content');return false">Print</button>
```

Comment: +1 - this works just great. I just wanted to add that putting the "return false;" in your javascript function won't work, it has to appear after the method in the onclick declaration. I was hoping the opposite was true and it isn't :(

Comment: after days of trying to get this to work, finally you serve it to us on a silver tray. Thanks

Comment: note if you use `onclick="return printElement('content');"` then you CAN use the return value, `true` or `false`, from the function. You just need to return _something_ from the onclick event itself (which is itself wrapped up in a function before exection), or it defaults to `true`.

Comment: OMG I spent 3 hours looking for "return false"!

Answer (score 51):

Add `type="button"` to your `<button>` tag like so:

```
<button type="button" onclick="printElement('content');">Print</button>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079197/1382306) explains the behavior.

Comment: Unbelievable.  I had the "type=button" part missing, and without it, "return false;" just had no effect.  Thanks for the tip !

Comment: This is the correct answer. I don't understand why that other answer got so many upvotes.

Comment: Also, `return false` does nothing and is not needed. `type=button` is essential.

Answer (score 7):

Alter you click event as below:

```
<button onclick="printElement('content');return false;">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

if you don't need a post back you should use an HTML button.

in that case you don't need override the behavior to avoid the post back and it's laighter to load (it doesn't need to be worked by the server to render back the HTML)

Comment: HTML button can't raise a post back itself. Probabily you are using the asp.net version.                                            <input type="button" value="something" onclick="alert('no postback')">

Comment: if it where an asp button i would write <asp:button not <button

Answer (score 4):

You should just use an input button instead:

```
<input type="button" onclick="printElement('content')" value="Print" />
```

This doesn't NEED an form (so you can use it without) and you don't have the problem with the postback.