# Can firebug or developer tools use to hack a web site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was facing to an interesting issue when implementing some role specific feature in a web site.

It's something like, if the logged in user has Admin role privileges then a button (called Transfer) will be **enabled** and otherwise for  other user it should be **disabled** (*So then they can't click hence can't perform the transaction / or invoke the relevant logic to that*)

At a glance it seems fairly straight forward UI validating kinda stuff. We just has to enable the button if the logged in user has the Admin privileges.

So after implementing that approach (working fine) , I was debugging the code using Chrome developer tools. *I noticed that though the button is now disabled we can actually enable it by removing the `disabled` part using the tool.*

[Just try it with this simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/L2nfsw9g/)

**And then I can click on it and the functions get invoked.** So basically it was not good approach. But fortunately there are service side validations also. But if not this can be a huge security vulnerability.

So basically doing an server / service  / back-end validation will prevent something dangerous from happening. But since the person can actually click on it and at least he can try to invoke the methods it seems not nice :(

So , I would really like to know , How can we prevent these kind of situations.

okay here is my question in simple :

**Is it good to have Disabled components at all?**

Comment: You cannot trust **anything** about the client. 100% of your security relies on server-side validation.

Comment: You often have to implement security twice: Once on the client (hide buttons or features they don't have access to) and once on the server (check to make sure they have permission to do something before you do it).  Yes, it's redundant but that's just how things work.

Comment: Attackers can and WILL send everything "not nice" possible to your server. This is not hypothetical. Your backend software must always validate data.

Comment: If the user should not be able to access it, don't render those components to start. In the end, the server should check to make sure the users can do the operation. In reality, a hacker does not even need to be on your page to do things, they can just make curl requests with payloads.

Comment: I agree with all of the answers to this question.  However, I'd like to add, Developer Tools like Firebug make this more convenient.  Anyone with access to the address bar can execute any JavaScript in the context of the open page.

Comment: Basic security principe: _never trust user input_, but disabled component is ok...

Comment: okay now why this question is closed ?

Answer (score 5):

*"Don't"* use disabled components in your *View*.
That's part of your business logic and should not appear in the DOM...

***"But hey :)..."***

Now, even it the element does not exists, nothing can stop a user to manually embed such element into your website.
**You should always perform server-side checks** to see it such user has the actual **privileges to perform a specific action**.

Sometimes `disabled` elements are used inside the UI to show the user:
*"Hey, see this button? It's not for you unless you pay or blah blah"*,
but usually as a ***second-step*/optional action element**.

Sometimes **entire forms** are *"visible"* on websites but dimed-out / **disabled**.
Such use cases are i.e: Payment forms with steps, where the designer wants to make wisible to the user that he needs to fill in a previous form in order to "Activate" the second one and proceed with the payment etc... Cases are endless, but if a form exists on the website it's pure UI (*View*) and the Model should never accept values from the controller unless (as I've said) specified by the Business Logic.

---

Remember that Front-end Javascript is used just to *inform* and help the user trough intuitive interface systems. JS events should just be there to reflect what a user can and cannot.

Since JS can be bypassed by any tech-savvy user, On the back-end side, you need to rebuild a similar and stronger security logic, once again.

**(!) Validate user inputs on front-end, but most importantly - in back-end.**

---

> Can firebug or developer tools use to hack a web site?

***Directly***?

- **Yes**

  - If the website back-end logic can be exploited by manipulating the View (source).
  - If you keep in the code that gets to the browser (in comments etc) sensitive informations.
- **No**

  - If a website does not allow XSS, has a strong back-end security.

***Indirectly***?

A malicious user could eventually ask a user to open console (tricking the user that Console is an actual website feature) and to send him (copy/paste) private information that are present in there, **such as session keys, cookies, etc...**

Comment: Nice answer. :) So in the later case, the problem still remains  I think. 
So how about we can have disabled components and if they are disabled then they should not have any events bind to them ? so they wont trigger anything

Comment: @prime don't mix JS events and logic with your back-end business logic. Anyone can sniff trough JS and see how it works. if you need it place your `disabled` element on page, but on the back-end side of your program ignore any input transactions if the session user is not allowed to trigger such actions. That way, even if a user makes an element `enabled` your back-end code will know that the user is a fool. Just you, don't get fooled.

Comment: hmm. security is a tough thing ah

Answer (score 0):

When the request is received by the server you should check if it is valid because I managed to get the button working in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: how that time affect in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server side programming language, you could use templates to generate your HTML pages so the componentes that are not allowed to certain users wouldn't even be rendered in the first place.

For Java, you have JSP/JSTL or JSF, for .Net you have ASP.Net and MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely validate everything that has to do with logins/permissions on the server side. Even if you change the site so that instead of disabling the element you never attach it to the DOM in the first place a tech savvy user can just try sending different data to your server and soliciting for meaningful response using wget or curl

Answer (score 0):

How do you prevent these situations?
Should you have disabled components?

The first questions answer gives you the second questions answer.

You shouldn't do this on the client side. However this is a common case and it's always recommended that you have server side checks in place to accommodate for people using developer tools to get around these things.

Another approach besides not implementing this is to abstract it.

If the user hasn't logged in don't even include the button in the DOM.
When they pass the specific parameters needed to give them the button you can use javascript to make a server side request, validate this and then inject the button appropriately, even in this case you should have another server side request validating the action after the button is triggered.

- Fulfilling button show parameters
- Validate
- Inject button
- Trigger button
- Validate
- Perform action

It really depends on how your application is laid out. In reality if you don't include the first two steps and only *hide* the button before validation there isn't any change in your application UX unless developers are a part of your audience because developers love to break things.

Can firebug or developer tools use to hack a web site?
If the applications data hasn't been secured or validated on the server then yes.

You should always check data coming in and validate it no matter the source external or internal.

Validation is your friend.